# How the run function of `pthread` modify the external variable?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* compute_prime (void* args) 
{
  int candidate = 2;
  int n = *((int*)args);

  while(1) {
    int factor;
    int is_prime = 1;
    for (factor = 2; factor < candidate; ++factor)
      if(candidate % factor == 0) {
    is_prime = 0;
    break;
      }
    if(is_prime){
      if(--n == 0)
    return (void*)candidate;
    }
    ++candidate;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread;
  int which_prime = 5000;
  int prime;
  pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime);

  pthread_join(thread, (void**)&prime);
  printf("The %d th prime number is %d.\n", which_prime, prime);
};
```

**the output is:**
`The 0 th prime number is 48611.`

What my confuse is "why `which_prime` becomes `0` in the main thread".

I think in function `void* compute_prime (void* args)`, the `n` is a copy of `which_prime`, then the modify is for `n`, not for `which_prime`, so what's the reason?

Comment: I don't see it either. Are you sure *this* is the code that prints `0` for `which_prime`?

Comment: @P.P. Yes, i am sure, you can try.

Comment: https://ideone.com/UCHLzi
Output: The 5000 th prime number is 48611.

Comment: Did you check what value is being set for 'n'? it seems that this is a memory address, not the actual value. it should be ** because args is a pointer, and it points on which_prime address

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Start by printing the pointers by using the correct printf specifier.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
pthread_join(thread, (void**)&prime);
```

is incorrect and leads to undefined behaviour. `&prime` is not a `void**` because `prime` is not a `void*`. Note that `void**` is **not** a "generic pointer-to-pointer" - it's a normal pointer, to a `void*`.

Instead, you should do this:

```
void *prime_result;
pthread_join(thread, &prime_result);
prime = (int)prime_result;
```

Most likely, `void*` and `int` are different sizes on your system and so trying to access `*(void**)&prime` results in memory corruption.

Comment: I am confuised about `void *prime_result;, prime = (int)prime_result;`, the type of `prime_result` is `void*`, how can it convert to `int`, is it ok?

Comment: @BlackMamba It's not very good C, but will work on all POSIX architectures which is where pthreads exist. The key here is to have the right types.

Comment: Personally, I rarely return anything but NULL from threads and instead pass a struct through pthread_create which contains both the "request" that the thread will execute and the results that the thread stores after it's done. It's cleaner from the point of view of allocations and casts. But it's a matter of style.